# Way to append dataframe to csv and rename file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was wondering if there was a way to append a dataframe to a csv file but also rename the file. For example I have a template csv that contains formulas and some conditional formatting. I also have a list of names, each name will later have its own dataframe and I would like to convert into it's own csv file. I don't want to keep having to copy and paste my formulas and formatting to these new csv's manually so that's where my question comes into play. I want to open my template csv, append the dataframe, but save it under a different name, so I can loop through all the names in the list and save them as separate files.

example:

```
names = [Tim, Dan, Kate]
food_df = pd.read_csv('foodlog.csv')
for x in names:
    ....
    ....
    with open("template.csv", 'a') as f:
    food_df.to_csv(f, str(x) + "foodsummary.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Desired Output:

```
Timfoodsummary.csv
Danfoodsummary.csv
Katefoodsummary.csv
```

While leaving my original template file intact. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shutil.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) to copy the `template.csv` to the same folder with new name and then append `food_df` to new csv.

```py
import shutil
import pandas as pd


names = [Tim, Dan, Kate]
food_df = pd.read_csv('foodlog.csv')

for name in names:
    filename = str(name) + "foodsummary.csv"
    shutil.copy("template.csv", filename)

    # Two methods to append to existing csv
    # 1. Specify append mode in the pandas `to_csv` function
    # food_df.to_csv(filename, mode='a', header=False)
    # 2. Open the file in append mode:
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        food_df.to_csv(f, encoding="utf-8")
```