# Efficient way to concatenate excel files

Tags: python, excel

I have a directory with roughly 100 excel files each ~50MB in size. Each file has multiple worksheets with inconsistent names.

I would like to concatenate them together.

What I have tried so far in python:

- concatenate and append via pandas (computer runs out swap memory [10G], also tried multiprocessing)
- put the files in a local sqlite3 database (too many columns)

Thanks in advance
Lukas

Comment: it's not clear whether all worksheets have the same columns or not. Anyway: try by appending to a CSV file. If columns can be added, keep track of them, and do a last pass adding the headers row and the missing fields (but still outputting a CSV file, this time with a header row)

Comment: some of them do, some of them not. thank you, I will try that. actually I tried exporting to .csv, but my pc ran out of memory

Comment: If you ran out of columns in Sqlite3 (max is 32Ki-1), you will do so even more in Excel (max is 16Ki). It seems to me you have to revise your expectations (I'm supposing you _did_ unify equivalent columns from different worksheets). Also, don't forget the max number of rows of Excel, which is 1Mi.

Answer (score 0):

If all worksheets have the same columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path
    
    
directory = Path('src/data') #the directory you want to use'
    
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        pd.read_excel(directory / filename).to_csv('src/Final.csv', header=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: thank you. files are actually .xlsx . does it make a difference?

Comment: You're welcome. Now it will concatenate .xlsx files.

Comment: This will most likely fail, since _"... Each file has multiple worksheets ..."_ and you are only reading the resp. first sheets (by default). You could set `sheet_name=None` to gather all. But I kind of dout that the result of the appending will be something meaningfull, since the workbooks seem to be inconsistent (not really clear).

Comment: The inconsistence is exactly the problem I have to deal with. This was also the reason, why I tried sheet_name=None and ran out of memory. Slowly I think I have to "polish" each dataset by hand and optimally convert it to .csv format for easier handling :(

Answer (score 0):

Kourosh's answer is completely appropriate, I would only add for the first file in a directory argument `header=True` in the `to_csv()` function, and for each subsequent file we can stay with `header=False`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have inconsistent column names** and still want to have all data gathered together in one file you can use the following script:

1. Put all excel workbooks (i.e. excel files) to be processed into a
   folder (see variable `paths`).
2. Get the paths of all workbooks in that folder using
   [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).
3. Return all worksheets of each workbook with [`read_excel(path, sheet_name=None)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel) and prepare them for merging.
4. Merge all worksheets with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat).
5. Export the final output, e.g., with [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) or [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html?highlight=to_excel#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel) (please note importantly that there is a row limit in Excel files).

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import glob

   paths = glob.glob(r"C:\excelfiles\*.xlsx")
   path_save = r"finished.xlsx"

   df_lst = [pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None).values() for path in paths]
   df_lst = [y.transpose().reset_index().transpose() for x in df_lst for y in x]
   df_result = pd.concat(df_lst, ignore_index=True)
   df_result.to_excel(path_save, index=False, header=False)
   ```

**Example with data**
Assume some Excel workbooks with some worksheets.

Worksheet1:

```
a   b   c
foo cor wal
bar gra plu
baz ult xyz
qux ply thu
```

Worksheet2:

```
u   v   w   x   y   z
12  92  86  22      80
23  29      74      21
16  10  75  67  61  99
```

Worksheet3:

```
I   II  III IV
1   5   9   1
2   6   0   6
3   7       3
4   8   2   0
```

Final output (after executing this snippet, i.e. after `to_excel`):

```
a   b   c
foo cor wal
bar gra plu
baz ult xyz
qux ply thu
u   v   w   x   y   z
12  92  86  22      80
23  29      74      21
16  10  75  67  61  99
I   II  III IV
1   5   9   1
2   6   0   6
3   7       3
4   8   2   0
```

---

**If you have consistent column names** use:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

paths = glob.glob(r"C:\excelfiles\*.xlsx")
path_save = r"C:\result\test.xlsx"

cdf = [pd.read_excel(excel_names, sheet_name=None).values()
            for excel_names in paths]
out_df = [y for x in cdf for y in x]
df_result = pd.concat(out_df, ignore_index=True)
df_result.to_excel(path_save, index=False)
```

Comment: This is reading _all_ the data into memory, which won't work, according to OP.

Comment: You could try to concatenate only portions of the data. And then append the portions to an existing csv file with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793037/13968392

Comment: I tried exactly this approach. as Timus said even extended swap memory runs full and into interrupt signal. What does the append function do, if column names change?